# Is there any offline translator for ubuntu that can be used from terminal?

Tags: translation

I am looking for a translator from Spanish and Portuguese to english that can be used to translate thousand of texts automatically. I used to use google translator, but the recently it has presented several [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group) that are not consistently solvable (it seems that google changed his policy). Is there any good offline option for ubuntu?

The translation need not to be as good as the one of google, since I am working with natural language processing and a model that considers the idea of "bags of words". So, the most important is to translate well the keywords.

Comment: [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) is much better than Google Translate for Spanish and Portuguese to English translation. DeepL plays fair with NLP.

Comment: @karel can I use it offline?

Comment: DeepL is a web application, not an offline app. You have to purchase a paid subscription to integrate DeepL’s translations into Computer Assisted Translation tools which offers a 30-day free trial.

Answer (score 1):

there is [argos-translate](https://github.com/argosopentech/argos-translate)

```sh
pip3 install argostranslate
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
argospm update
argospm install translate-en_de
argos-translate --from en --to de "Hello World!"
```